# Multiple windows in Mathematica help

Tags: front-end

I'm new in Mathematica, and would like to know how can I open multiple help windows at the same time. It's this possible? I'm using Mac OS.

I know it works for link in the help page with right mouse click, but not for drill down in another function (that is not a link).

Comment: You can do Help-> Documentation Center as many times as you wish.

Comment: Shift + F1 instead of F1

Comment: you can right click on hyperlinks in the help system and select "open in new window"

Comment: @Rojo tks, it's exactly this, but unfortunately Shift + F1 works just for Windows, not for Mac.

Comment: Find KeyEventTranslations.tr and look for a line like this ` Item[KeyEvent["F1", Modifiers->{Shift}], SelectionHelpDialog[False]],`. If nothing similar is there, try adding it

Comment: @Rojo, this line already existes in my Mac KeyEventTranslations.tr. I think it's a bug. I tried to change Shift to Command for a test, but without success.

Comment: Does this open a new help window? `Documentation\`HelpLookup["Graphics"]`. If so, perhaps tweaking that keyEventTranslations might work

Comment: @Rojo the last command works om Mac.

Comment: @Rojo Yes..! It works. Do you know how to implement it in `KeyEventTranslations.tr`?

Comment: Backup all. Try removing that line to KeyEventTranslations.tr, and adding this one to MenuSetup.tr, inside `HelpMenu["&Help",....]`.

Comment: `MenuItem["&Search help in new window",  KernelExecute[FrontEndTokenExecute["ExpandSelection"];Documentation\`HelpLookup@FE\`makePlainText@NotebookRead@InputNotebook[]],MenuKey["F1", Modifiers -> {Shift}], MenuEvaluator->Automatic],`

Comment: @Rojo I fell we are almost there! The command works (selection) just if I remove the `Documentation`HelpLookup@‌FE`makePlainText@NotebookRead@InputNotebook[]` part of it.

Comment: Try to come to the chat, I'm not sure if you can. Without knowing what error you got I'm not sure how to help

Comment: @Rojo Please consider posting an answer, to be honest I was not aware of this :P

Comment: @Jens since Rojo is not willing to, and I can't test it, maybe you can find time to add the answer?

Comment: @Kuba OK, I'll try that again - can't do it right now because I want to upgrade to the 10.1 version first...

Answer (score 3):

I ll write this as an answer even though it is given in the comment (thanks @acl) as this is going to be a life changer for me.
The solution is

> Right (or on a mac control) click on the item and it will give you the option to open a new window.

For instance, let's assume one is looking at this tutorial [`howto/WorkWithDifferentialEquations`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/WorkWithDifferentialEquations.html)
and you want to visit the page Solve a Differential-Algebraic equation *and* keep the howto page open.

So you have

[image: Mathematica graphics]

After one right clicks

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Select open in new window et...

> Voila!

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I have been frustrated  about what I thought was this missing feature for years!

Thanks again StackExchange!

### Complement

As a side note, I also did not realize that the frontend allows you to open more than once the documentation center.